# Why does kendoForm fire twice when clicking submit?

Tags: kendo-ui

If in a kendoForm after domReady with setOptions the formData is set, so submit fires twice with one click.

```
form.setOptions({
 formData : { ID: 2, Name: "Tom", Address: "Berlin" }
});
```

My example code: [kendoForm example](https://dojo.telerik.com/EYuSeFuj/9)

First press submit Button => submit fires ones.

Second press add FormData Button, then press submit => submit fires twice.

What is my mistake that fires twice after setOptions submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described behavior is related to a known issue in the Form that is logged here:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/5854

As a temporary workaround until the issue is resolved with an official fix, you can use override the _setEvents function as follows:

```
<script>
        kendo.ui.Form.fn._setEvents = function() {
          var that = this,
              validator = that.validator;

          validator
            .bind("validateInput", $.proxy(that._validateField, that))
            .bind("validate", $.proxy(that._validate, that));

          that.wrapper
            .on("submit.kendoForm", $.proxy(that._submit, that))
            .on("clear.kendoForm", $.proxy(that._clear, that))
            .on("click.kendoForm", ".k-form-clear", $.proxy(that._clear, that));

          that._model.bind("change", $.proxy(that._change, that));
        }
      </script>
```

[Here is a working Dojo example](https://dojo.telerik.com/AWAFiDAF/9) for your convenience.